# Can I make my desktop background active?

Tags: 12.04, unity

I want my desktop background to look like the Chrome extension, [Currently](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ojhmphdkpgbibohbnpbfiefkgieacjmh).

[image: Currently, a Google Chrome extension that replaces the New Tab screen with the time, date, and weather.]

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give you similar conky script but no 100%. You need to change the font, alignment and icon set.

**Result**

[image]

**Step 1.**

Install conky

```
sudo apt-get install conky
```

**Step 2.**

Install conky forecast

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conky-companions/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install conkyforecast
```

**Step 3.**

**Save at home folder**

- [**.conky1**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1258945/)
- [**.conky2**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1258956/)
- [**.weather-ob**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1258958/)
- [**.conkyForecast.config**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1258963/)

**Step 4.**

Open `.conky2` and locate **`--location=MYXX0006`**

Replace **`MYXX0006`** with you location code.

You can find your code [**here**](http://xoap.weather.com/search/search?where=Malaysia)

**Step 5.**

Run your conky

**By terminal:**

```
conky -c ~/.conky1
conky -c ~/.conky2
```

**Make startup application**

Open startup application

> **Name** : Conky1
>
> **Command** : conky -p 20 -c ~/.conky1
>
> **Name** : Conky2
>
> **Command** : conky -p 20 -c ~/.conky2

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to install **Conky** (available in the Ubuntu Software Center) before beginning

Then look for and install the Conky theme you want.  You may not get it exactly as your screen shot shows but the **Gotham** Conky theme comes close

[Browse here for more conky themes on devianart.com](http://browse.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&global=1&q=conky)